# ReferenceError: process is not define with libraryTarget: umd

Tags: webpack, umd, webpack-plugin

With `webpack.config.js`

```
  devtool: false,
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'mylib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    sourceMapFilename: `[name].js.map`,
  },
  ...
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
    NODE_ENV: 'development',
    POUCHDB_NAME: 'dbname'
  }),
```

When I try to open in browser (`index.html`) ...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
>       at Object. (db.js:8)
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (main.js:12716)
>       at Object.crypto (main.js:12727)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 2becb557cb7088856bca:19)
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (main.js:18506)
>       at Object. (main.js:18519)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 2becb557cb7088856bca:19)
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (_replacer.js:8)
>       at Object. (_replacer.js:8)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 2becb557cb7088856bca:19)

In `db.js` I have ..

```
const { POUCHDB_NAME = 'mydb' } = process.env;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DefinePlugin` instead of `EnvironmentPlugin`

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
            'process.env.POUCHDB_NAME': JSON.stringify(process.env.POUCHDB_NAME || 'mydb'),
        })
```